# Spring/Swagger download a docx file generates a corrupted document

Tags: spring, swagger

Spring/Swagger,  download a docx file generates a corrupted document. I found several similar articles but I dont reach to get my code running.

PDF and a normal txt File works as expected. I hope you can help me I don't know where to find more information

Interface Class/Method

@ApiOperation(value = "Create a customer invoice", nickname = "createBill", notes = "With this command you can create a invoice for a specfic customer and month", tags={ "Bill", })

```
@ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "successful operation") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Bill/CreateBill/{customerid}/{month}/{year}",
        produces = {"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<?> createBill(@ApiParam(value = "Customer number",required=true) @PathVariable("customerid") String customerid,@ApiParam(value = "Month",required=true) @PathVariable("month") Integer month,@ApiParam(value = "Year",required=true) @PathVariable("year") Integer year);
```

Implemeted Class/Method

```
                      responseHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"));
                      responseHeaders.set("Content-Disposition",
                                     "attachment; filename=test.docx");

                      File file = new File("c:/temp/report.docx");


                      final InputStream in =  new FileInputStream(file);

                      responseHeaders.setContentLength((int) file.length());

                      return ResponseEntity.ok()
                              .header("Content-Disposition",
                                      "attachment; filename=docx.zip")
                              .contentType(new MediaType("application", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"))
                              .contentLength((int) file.length())
                              .body(IOUtils.toByteArray(in));
```

Comment: The media type says 'this is a docx document'. The file extension says 'this is a zip archive'. Which one is it?

Comment: Yes you are right. I was trying something and I forgot to replace it again . Please replace it with .docx